# Copy to clipboard in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, clipboard

Is there any way to copy a string to the clipboard with Inno Setup?

I need to implement a button to copy the contents of a field to clipboard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can send the [`WM_COPY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649022%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message. For example:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
const
  WM_COPY = $0301;

var
  EditToCopy: TNewEdit;

procedure CopyToClipboard(Control: TWinControl);
begin
  SendMessage(Control.Handle, WM_COPY, 0, 0);
end;

procedure ButtonCopyClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  EditToCopy.SelectAll;
  CopyToClipboard(EditToCopy);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  ButtonCopy: TNewButton;
  WizardPage: TWizardPage;
begin
  WizardPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Description');
  EditToCopy := TNewEdit.Create(WizardForm);
  EditToCopy.Parent := WizardPage.Surface;
  EditToCopy.Text := 'Text to copy';
  ButtonCopy := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  ButtonCopy.Parent := WizardPage.Surface;
  ButtonCopy.Caption := 'Copy';
  ButtonCopy.Top := EditToCopy.Top + EditToCopy.Height + 8;
  ButtonCopy.OnClick := @ButtonCopyClick;
end;
```